# Leaks using makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm a beginner in C programming and I faced an issue with valgrind, here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   printf("Hello World ");
}
```

When I do a Makefile to run it :

```
run: compile
     ./a.out

compile: 
        gcc test.c
```

I run with valgrind make and I have an error that told me that there is a still reachable blocks ,
when I compile without Makefile I have 0 Error , can someone help me to resolve it ?

Comment: did you intend to `return 0;`? `gcc` also will compile all sorts of things if you don't have it least warn with flags like `-Wall`; there are many options available to warn or error for issues!

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I tried to run with -Wall -o test and run with ./test in Makefile  without returning 0 but I have the same issues

Comment: What if you run `./a.out` with Valgrind? It sounds like you catch leaks in `make` program itself

Comment: What is the exact command you run? What is the exact output from valgrind?

Comment: Note also that having allocated memory still reachable at program termination is not a memory leak *per se*, and it usually is not an issue of much concern.

Comment: You can't run `valgrind make`.  I never understand why people create `run` targets in makefiles; isn't it easier to just run the command directly?  In any event if you want to do this you'll need to create a `valgrind` target that runs your program under valgrind, like this: `valgrind: compile ; valgrind ./a.out`  now you can run `make valgrind`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have 0 errors when I run it with valgrind ./a.out

Comment: Then you have nothing to worry about (except the correct tool usage).

Comment: @Jens I tape on terminal valgrind make

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you , its clear for me now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I run

```
valgrind make
```

but not if I run

```
make compile
valgrind ./a.out
```

The first is testing an entirely different thing (the memory usage of `make`) than is the second (the memory usage of `./a.out`).

Like @MadScientist, I really don't understand why people create plain `run` targets, but it does make some sense to me that they would create a target to test with valgrind.  If you wanted such a target then it would look something like this (in light of the rest of the Makefile):

```
leakcheck: compile
    valgrind ./a.out
```

Comment: Just to close the loop: as John says in comments above, it's no problem if your program reports memory in use when it exits.  The operating system will always reclaim all that memory anyway when your process exits.  The only thing freeing all that memory before exit does, is complicate the shutdown of your program and make it take longer.  I know some people disagree but they're not right :).  If you have LEAKS (that is, unreferenced and unfreed memory) that's bad.  If you have referenced but not freed memory, that's fine.  All GNU tools take this approach, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

On some systems, the Standard I/O layer of the C Programming Language allocates buffers that valgrind reports as reachable even for tiny programs such as yours.

I have used systems where this is the case. To free the Standard I/O resources you can close the Standard I/O streams before returning from `main`, as described in the C99 7.21.5.1 Description of `fclose`

> A successful call to the fclose function causes the stream pointed to by stream to be
> flushed and the associated file to be closed. Any unwritten buffered data for the stream
> are delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; any unread buffered data
> are discarded. Whether or not the call succeeds, the stream is disassociated from the file
> and any buffer set by the setbuf or setvbuf function is disassociated from the stream
> (and deallocated if it was automatically allocated).

The parenthetical remark at the end of that paragraph is the hint.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     /* ... */
     fclose(stdin);
     fclose(stdout);
     fclose(stderr);
     return 0;
}
```